# Installing SAP HANA tools on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hana

I installed Eclipse Oxygen (64-bit) on Windows and then installed SAP HANA Tools for Eclipse. I have had to repeat this installation each time I restart Eclipse and it is frustrating. I am sure this is not normal, but I am very new to HANA and to Eclipse IDE as well. What do I need to do to make this installation "stay" so that I do not have to repeat the steps each time?
Thanks

Comment: never had this issue (and been working with SAP HANA from before it was generally available). Best guess here: maybe a privilege issue with the Eclipse installation. Do other plug-ins "stay" put?

Comment: You didn't specify which OS you install Eclipse on, but if it's Linux, very likely it's a perrmissions issue. I had such problems when I installed Eclipse/addons under root, and then launch the Eclipse as regular user. Usually root installations are invisible in that case.

Comment: @LarsBr. I do not have any other plug-ins yet. I just began using Eclipse for SAP HANA a couple days ago. Suncatcher, it is Windows 10 Pro. I do not have admin privileges, but I installed Eclipse and HANA plug-in under my login.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, this is not normal. I have posted a blog on the SAP HANA community about installing SAP HANA studio that you may find helpful: https://blogs.sap.com/2017/12/15/sap-hana-2.0-studio-installation-and-update-by-the-sap-hana-academy/

It could very well be a "Run as Administrator" issue, as Lars mentioned.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, link only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :)